# SASS/SCSS LoadError when using --watch

Tags: sass

I have no trouble building SCSS to CSS output using `sass styles.scss test.css --style expanded` in terminal.  However, when I try to use `--watch`, I get a LoadError.

Here's the output I get using --trace:

```
MilleniumFalcon: ~/AuroraFX Studios/Labs/_test +[git:master]
R2-D2:/> sass --watch styles.scss:test.css --style expanded --trace
```

> > > Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
> > >       /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rb-fsevent (LoadError)
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:207:in `load_dependent_adapter'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:198:in`usable?'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:190:in `usable_and_works?'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:57:in`block in select_and_initialize'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:55:in `each'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:55:in`select_and_initialize'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:291:in `initialize_adapter'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:283:in`setup'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:65:in `start!'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:291:in`listen_to'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:257:in `watch'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/lib/sass/plugin.rb:108:in`method_missing'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/lib/sass/exec.rb:509:in `watch_or_update'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/lib/sass/exec.rb:346:in`process_result'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/lib/sass/exec.rb:43:in `parse'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/lib/sass/exec.rb:22:in`parse!'
> > >           from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.3.4/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'
> > >           from /usr/bin/sass:23:in`load'
> > >           from /usr/bin/sass:23:in `'

Comment: try pasting the stack trace, so we can read it.

Comment: I replaced the screenshot with a --trace paste.